# Launch HTML file in Chrome with parameters

Tags: windows, html, chrome

I want to create a shortcut that launches chrome with an HTML file in the same directory as the shortcut. I also need it to launch chrome with the following parameters `--new-window --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/chromedev"`

Currently the "Target" line of my shortcut looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ./specViewer.html --new-window --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/chromedev"
```

Launching this gives me the `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error

I've also tried this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" specViewer.html --new-window --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/chromedev"
```

With no such luck, as then it tries to search the internet for my file.

Any ideas on a solution to properly launch the local file in chrome with the command line parameters?

Comment: I also just tried using a `.bat` file, which would properly launch the correct `HTML` file, but without the command line parameters. For some reason those are not working

Comment: Also found this link where they are talking about it in chrome https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/jp2R-xZG49Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's answer is correct as far as it goes. However, you can get a Windows shortcut to launch relative to the current directory.

While you can use [Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) in shortcuts, there are a few volatile ones that cannot be used (such as `%CD%`).

As the OP suggested, using a batch file is an excellent way to bypass this restriction:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///%CD%/specViewer.html" --user-data-dir="C:/chromedev" --disable-web-security --new-window
```

You can also create a `New Shortcut` with the following properties:

```
Target:      "%WINDIR%\system32\cmd.exe" /c start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///%CD%/specViewer.html" --user-data-dir="C:/chromedev" --disable-web-security --new-window
Start in:    
Change Icon: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

**CRITICAL:** make sure `Start in` is empty; this will start command prompt in the current directory.

Notice how we launched command prompt, which can use dynamic variables such as `%CD%`. And you'll probably want to change the icon on the shortcut to look like Google Chrome, or whatever program you are launching.

---

*For more on the peripheral details, see this question:*

[Making a Windows shortcut start relative to where the folder is? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169556)

Comment: I like you're answer. I've already distributed my html file with the batch script. If I ever need to do this again, I will have try this out! I am marking yours as accepted since it mentioned my answer also

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve my problem by instead using a `.bat` file and using this as it's content

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///%cd%/specViewer.html" --user-data-dir="C:/chromedev" --disable-web-security --new-window
```

Note: prefixing that command is `START` breaks it.

Comment: Using `START` or `CALL` is not always necessary, but prefixing the above command with `START "title"` will fix it again. You need the *"title"* argument, even if it is just a pair of empty quotes. See also: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html